# When is the select-able ROS2 Middle-ware architecture planned have a public release

Tags: ros2, zenoh

Currently ROS2 is using DDS as middle-ware , I want to use https://zenoh.io/ or any other middle-ware for ROS2 is this possible ? I read in the forum that the migration to achieve any Middle-ware to be  used in ROS2 is in progress . When is the select-able ROS2 Middle-ware architecture planned go on a  public release.

Answer (score 1):

As Steve mentioned, the `RMW_IMPLEMENTATION` is a feature already present in ROS2 since the very early stages. Since you mentioned Zenoh, you might be referring to the new `rmw_alternate` [feature planned for the upcoming ROS 2 Jazzy release](https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/blob/rolling/source/The-ROS2-Project/Roadmap.rst#jazzy-roadmap). May 2024 is the tentative date set in the roadmap.

Answer (score 0):

Its already selectable via the `RMW_IMPLEMENTATION` environmental variable. You can select at run-time any of the available options.